# How do you load a json model in threejs using reactjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, three.js

I am developing this project where I want to use Threejs in Reactjs.
So, I have this JSON model which is loading when I developing in normal HTML but it's throwing this error in React.

THREE:ObjectLoader: Can't parse ./../JSON/monkey.json. Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

This occurs when I use:>

```
loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader()
loader.load( './../JSON/monkey.json', function ( geometry, materials ) 
{
  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({morphTargets: true});
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);
});
```

And, when I try with:

```
loader = new THREE.JSONLoader()
```

it's throwing this error:>
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Any suggestions on what could be the issue.

Comment: Can you please share your `monkey.json` in this thread? Besides, `ObjectLoader` and `JSONLoader` load different types of JSON. You can't use them for the same file. Besides, the `onLoad()` callback of `ObjectLoader.load()` has a different signature than `JSONLoader.load()`. Check out the doc pages of both loaders for more information: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html

Comment: Do you actually have a `<` token?

Comment: You could probably use something like https://jsonlint.com/ or some other json validator if you can't share the monkey with the world.

Comment: The `<...` token often means a `404 Not Found`, check developer tools for errors to see if the model is actually at the path you're requesting.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the late reply. This is the link from where I downloaded the monkey.json and monkey_animated.json >  https://github.com/cjgammon/diving-in/blob/master/threejs/threejs-7_models.zip